# LinqPad - EntityFramework 4.3.1 - MissingMethodException - Sql Compact

Tags: .net-4.0, sql-server-ce, linqpad, entity-framework-4.3, missingmethodexception

I have my POCO model is seperate dll than my asp.net mvc 3 website.

I created new connection in LinqPad Beta: v4.41.01 selected option for Poco, provided path to custom dll, Chose DbContext, Chose via parameterless constructor.

This did not work, as I am using SqlServer Compact.

Then I created dummy.config file as follows:

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
   <configuration>
    <configSections>
        <section name="entityFramework" type="System.Data.Entity.Internal.ConfigFile.EntityFrameworkSection, EntityFramework, Version=4.3.1.0,  Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b77a5c561934e089" />
  </configSections>
  <entityFramework>
  <defaultConnectionFactory type="System.Data.Entity.Infrastructure.SqlCeConnectionFactory, EntityFramework">
    <parameters>
      <parameter value="System.Data.SqlServerCe.4.0" />
    </parameters>
  </defaultConnectionFactory>
</entityFramework>
    <connectionStrings>
        <add name="ModelContext"
             connectionString="data source=database.sdf"
             providerName="system.data.sqlserverce.4.0" />
    </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

With this, Test on connection is shown successful. Even, tree on left is also populated. But when I run any query, it throws exception as follows:
Method not found: 'System.Data.Entity.DbSet`1 InventoryModelContext.get_xxx()'.

**EDIT**: Also, note that this seems to be compilation error!

Any solution or workaround? Am I missing something?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem as well, it started without any apparent reason - did not change anything in my environment.

I am using EF4.2 Poco, LINQPad 4.42.01

**To resolve I started running LINQPad as *Administartor***, it solved it. I am not sure what has changed that made it break, I have not used LINQPad for a while, so maybe it was some auto-update of LINQPad or something like that.

**Update:** After reinstalling, for some reason the Administartor trick was not working, a new method I found is query first without specifying a database (at the top right, it says `<None>`), then i get an error that what I am querying for does not exists in this context, and then I set the database to the correct context, and it works.

Still not sure what is actually causing it.